# How to resolve ruby module/mixin method conflict

Tags: ruby, inheritance, methods

In the following, `A` inherits `F`, which inherits `E`, so calling `initialize` on an `A` instance calls `A#initialize`, which has priority over `E#initialize` and `F#initialize`.

```rb
module E
  def initialize(e)
    @e = e
  end

  def e
    @e
  end
end

module F
  def initialize(f)
    @f = f
  end

  def f
    @f
  end
end

class A
  include E
  include F

  def initialize(e, f)
    # ...
  end
end
```

I need to refer to both `E#initialize` and `F#initialize` from within the method body of `A#initialize`, passing `e` and `f` respectively as the argument so that I get this result:

```
a = A.new("foo", "bar")
a.e # => "foo"
a.f # => "bar"
```

Is there a way to refer to those methods?

Comment: you can't initialize modules

Comment: Code smell. I think something is wrong with your architecture. This is probably an XY-question.

Comment: @sawa You are probably right, this is a bit code smellish, I'm more trying to make things automatic for the programmer. I really liked Amadan 's answer below, super helpful and simple syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem for you is that there is no multiple inheritance in Ruby; so the modules get inserted as an ancestor one above the other, and as such `F#initialize` overshadows `E#initialize`. As you found, it is easy to access `F#initialize` using `super(f)`; but the other one needs a hack to access: we can pick the `initialize` method directly off of the module, because it is an ancestor; then bind it to the current object and run it.

```
def initialize(e, f)
  E.instance_method(:initialize).bind(self).call(e)
  F.instance_method(:initialize).bind(self).call(f) # equivalent to super(f)
end
```

However, I do not recommend this. If you need to run several initialisers, you'd be better off using composition, rather than inheritance (and to be clear, `include` is inheritance).

Comment: but it's not right to have an initialize method in a module ?

Comment: Nice :) But still, if someone needs to do this, they're doing something wrong and actually need fix their design.

Comment: @Xero: Why not? `initialize` is just a method like any other. It has a certain special significance because it is called by `Class.new`, but that's it. I agree that this is ugly as sin, but it does work.

Comment: @Xero there's nothing wrong with `def initialize` in a module. It won't create a `module.new` method for you, but you can include it into a class and it will work fine. A bit unconventional, but not wrong.

Comment: 100% what I'm looking for, I'm familiar with instance_exec and figured that might be part of the answer but this perfectly sums it up. I really love this `instance_method(:name).bind(self)` method!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Method#super_method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Method.html#method-i-super_method) for this.

```
module E
  def initialize(e)
    @e = e
  end
  def e
    @e
  end
end

module F
  def initialize(f)
    @f = f
  end

  def f
    @f
  end
end
```

```
class A
  include E
  include F

  def initialize(e, f)
    select_initialize(E).call e
    select_initialize(F).call f
  end

  private

  def select_initialize(mod) 
    self.class.
         ancestors.
         index(mod).
         times.
         reduce(method(:initialize)) { |m,_| m.super_method }
  end
end

puts A.new("E", "F").f
  #=> F
puts A.new("E", "F").e
  #=> E
```

Note:

```
A.ancestors
  #=> [A, F, E, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

See also [Module#ancestors](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.2/Module.html#method-i-ancestors), [Array#index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-index), [Integer#times](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Integer.html#method-i-times), [Enumerable#reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (aka `inject`), [Object#method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Object.html#method-i-method) and [Method#call](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Method.html#method-i-call).

`E` and `F` may of course contain other instance methods that are needed by instances of the class.

Comment: I was thinking about this, but I prefer picking the method directly off of the module; this way you need to be conscious of which modules are included and in which order (and gods help you if you include another below them at a later date...) In fact, I should probably not use `super` at all, for this exact reason, and pick off both methods directly. :D +1 tho

Comment: @Amadan, I made a change that should address your concern about the ordering of `include` statements.